# Packing material vocabulary

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

In English, there are quite a few words to describe materials used to pad and insulate packages that are being shipped from one place to another:

- **packing peanuts** or **foam peanuts** are individual pieces of small foam
- **bubble wrap** describes sheets of plastic with many small embedded bubbles of air
- **Styrofoam** is a material often found padding objects during shipment
- **shrink wrap** is a plastic film that forms a seal over an object
- **padding** refers generally to any material that cushions objects
- **packing materials** is a general term describing any of the objects above

How would each of these terms be best translated to Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spain:

- packing peanuts: there's no formal word. On my neck of the woods, we use "palomitas" (popcorn)
- bubble wrap: papel de burbujas
- Styrofoam: again, no formal word that I know of. I use "porexpán", which I believe is a commercial name for the product (you can check other names elsewhere in http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poliestireno_expandido )
- shrink wrap: no specific name... "plástico"
- padding: relleno
- packing materials: material de embalaje or material para empaquetar

Comment: A Colombian would translate `packing peanuts` as `bolitas de icopor` and `Styrofoam` as `Icopor` (Industria COlombiana de PORosos - ICOPOR). Other than that; same as Alex's answer.

Comment: @Icarus:  You should make your own answer so we can upvote that one too.  :)

Comment: @ethan furman thanks, I will do that next time :)

Answer (score 1):

In Bolivia, I learned "PLASTOFOR" for STYROFOAM, and in Chile we call it "PLUMAVIT". All three are presumably brand names or trademarks for "poliestireno expandido", the generic name for a relatively modern material.
Shrink wrap is known in Chile as "alusa" or as "estretch film".